# Blurry text after DPI change

Tags: windows-10, dpi

My laptop has 1920x1080 resolution and a size of 15,5. The external monitor I use has the same resolution, but it is 24". If I move a window to the external monitor, the text becomes huge, and vice versa.
Windows 10 lets me change the DPI settings separately, but the result is far from great. I set 125% for my laptop, but after that text on the *unchanged* external monitor became extremely blurred, in *some* applications:

- Firefox is fine
- IE is fine
- Outlook and Excel look horrible

Is there some way to get sharp text in both monitors without going back to wildly different sizes?

Answer (score 2):

Even the very latest version of Microsoft Office is not per-monitor DPI aware. There is nothing you can do. Except perhaps complain to Microsoft.

For applications that are not per-monitor DPI aware, Windows takes over scaling them. By resizing the rendered output, resulting in blurry display.

Because Windows makes those applications use the main monitor DPI setting, they look awful on all *other* displays with different DPI settings.

To find out out about an application’s DPI awareness, you can use Sysinternals Process Explorer. It offers a “DPI Awareness” column for its process list.

Comment: I'm finding this problem to be a lot worse on Windows 10 vs previous editions. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DuncanJones Windows 10 brings a lot of changes concerning DPI scaling, especially with multiple monitors. I don't really see any problems either, but that's just my impression. Downscaled output could certainly be better, but that really cannot be helped, unless someone invents a magic new downscaling algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This depends of the GDI framework used by the application
Older ones have this side effect, that is noticeable when font size is > 125% and mostly on big screen